# Locking down Gradle to only use our internal repository during CI builds

Tags: maven, gradle

I've fairly recently started to learn Gradle as it seems a whole lot more flexible and intuitive than Maven.

One particular issue that I've yet to understand is how to lock down the usage of external repositories when doing CI builds.
[Hans Dockter](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5a91dBLX8Qc) mentioned this as a great and simple use-case but I haven't seen any examples of it so far.

In Maven, what I would do is to add our company repo to the CI user's settings.xml file and making it a mirror of all other repositories. This way even though a developer has set his own repositories in the POM, our artifactory is still used as the cache.

Is there any way I can achieve the same using Gradle, perhaps in some startup script or similar?

Answer (score 1):

Failed to realise that the Gradle user guide actually has this concrete example in the chapter concerning startup scripts.

http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/init_scripts.html

Guess it's time to RTFM..